# Достаточно ли одного объекта-монитора для нескольких методов или каждому нужен свой?

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть класс, который я должен сделать потокобезопасным, без применения конкаренси коллекций. И в этом классе есть целый ряд методов, я использую один объект-монитор, на все методы, но я не уверен достаточно ли этого или надо на каждый метод свой? Или на оборот он и должен быть один, что-бы пропускать только один поток?

```
public class UserStorage implements Storage {
    private Map<Integer, Account> accounts;
    private final Object monitor;

    UserStorage() {
        this.accounts = new HashMap<>();
        this.monitor = new Object();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAccount(final Account account) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            Account a = this.accounts.get(account.getId());
            if (a != null) {
                return false;
            }

            this.accounts.put(account.getId(), account);
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String viewAccount(final Integer id) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            Account account = this.accounts.get(id);
            if (account != null) {
                return account.toString();
            }

            return "Account not found.";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updateAccount(final Integer id, final String name) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            Account oldVersion = this.accounts.get(id);
            if (oldVersion != null) {
                Account updatedAccount = new User(
                        oldVersion.getAmount(), name, id
                );

                this.accounts.put(id, updatedAccount);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delAccount(final Integer id) {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            Account account = this.accounts.get(id);
            if (account != null) {
                this.accounts.remove(id);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему не сделать методы synchronized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Писал в ответе на другой ваш вопрос. На работу с каждым Map или наборов объектов-переменных описывающих одну из низких бизнес-логик заводить отдельный lock. лучше всего StampedLock или ReadWriteLock